# point cloud "box" filtering

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just wanted to know if a package doing a "box" filtering already exists. I'd just like to limit the field of view of the Kinect, by removing everything that's not in a given box. I googled a bit and couldn't find an already implemented solution.

If it doesn't exist, I guess I can create a node and use the [passthrough filter](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php), but I thought it would already be implemented.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10121/point-cloud-%22box%22-filtering/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 0

Comment: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/105421/884 has a single nodelet answer using `pcl/CropBox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I finally found the answer: I just needed to start a passthrough nodelet with the correct parameters. Here is a working launch file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <group ns="/pcl_filters">
    <!-- PCL Manager -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="box_filter_pcl_manager" args="manager" output="screen"/>

    <!-- Run a passthrough filter to delimit in x direction -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="psx" args="load pcl/PassThrough box_filter_pcl_manager" output="screen">
      <remap from="~input" to="/camera/depth/points" />
      <rosparam>
        filter_field_name: x
        filter_limit_min: -.8
        filter_limit_max: 0.5
      </rosparam>
    </node>

    <!-- Run a passthrough filter to delimit in y direction -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="psy" args="load pcl/PassThrough box_filter_pcl_manager" output="screen">
      <remap from="~input" to="psx/output" />
      <rosparam>
        filter_field_name: y
        filter_limit_min: -1.
        filter_limit_max: .3
      </rosparam>
    </node>

    <!-- Run a passthrough filter to delimit in z direction -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="psz" args="load pcl/PassThrough box_filter_pcl_manager" output="screen">
      <remap from="~input" to="psy/output" />
      <rosparam>
        filter_field_name: z
        filter_limit_min: 0.0
        filter_limit_max: 2.0
      </rosparam>
    </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-01**:
I think you mean @dejanpan's solution :)

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-31**:
Ok, it didn't work with one filter, I just pasted Erik's solution here to have the answer directly accessible. Thanks.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-31**:
Hm, to be honest I haven't really tested it, I just subscribed to the output point cloud and saw that I had a smaller point cloud. I'll have to check this.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-31**:
Don't the later rosparam blocks overwrite the earlier ones?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ugo, this is launch file I was using a while ago:

[http://code.cs.tum.edu/indefero/index.php/p/mapping/source/tree/master/pcl_cloud_tools/launch/box_filter.launch](http://code.cs.tum.edu/indefero/index.php//p/mapping/source/tree/master/pcl_cloud_tools/launch/box_filter.launch) .

The filtered cloud comes on psz/output topic.
D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-05-31**:
Hmm, I did not really measure CPU usage to be honest. But yeah if your example works better I am happy to adopt it. D.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-31**:
Thanks for that. Do we really need the 3 passthrough filters? Isn't it a big overhead?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-31**:
Hmm... for some reason that link doesn't seem to want to linkify...