# Cutting off a pointcloud2 at a certain range

Tags: ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a mapping problem with a laser scanner. I want to cut off the 20% of points that are furthest away from the robot. So this distance should be variable for each time steps. Depending on how close we are to walls in certain areas.
I came up with the following approach:

```
void PcFilter::pcCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &pointcloud_in)
{
    unsigned int num_points = pointcloud_in->width;
    std::vector<float> ranges(num_points);
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pointcloud_out;
    int cut_off_idx = int(num_points*0.8);
    pointcloud_out.header = pointcloud_in->header;
    pointcloud_out.fields = pointcloud_in->fields;
    pointcloud_out.height = pointcloud_in->height;
    pointcloud_out.width = cut_off_idx;//+1
    pointcloud_out.point_step = pointcloud_in->point_step;
    pointcloud_out.row_step = pointcloud_out.width*pointcloud_out.point_step;
    pointcloud_out.is_bigendian = pointcloud_in->is_bigendian;
    pointcloud_out.is_dense = pointcloud_in->is_dense;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> iter_x(*pointcloud_in, "x");
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> iter_y(*pointcloud_in, "y");
    int count = 0;
    //iterate over pointcloud an save the distance from the points in the xy plane
    for(;iter_x != iter_x.end();
        ++iter_x, ++iter_y)
    {
        ranges[count] = hypot(*iter_x, *iter_y);
        count++;
    }
    std::sort(std::begin(ranges), std::end(ranges));
    float cut_off_dist = ranges[cut_off_idx];
    float point_dist;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> iter_xx(*pointcloud_in, "x");
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> iter_yy(*pointcloud_in, "y");
    //iterate over pointcloud again and fill data in new pointcloud
    for(;iter_xx != iter_xx.end(); ++iter_xx, ++iter_yy)
    {
        point_dist = hypot(*iter_x, *iter_y);
        if (point_dist <= cut_off_dist)
        {

            //todo fill in data
            //pointcloud_out.data  =0;
        }
    }
    pub_pc2_.publish(pointcloud_out);
    }
```

What I cant seem to accomplish is actually filling the data field with the corresponding points. I saw sth about memcpy, but I could find an extensive tutorial. Appreciate your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289820/cutting-off-a-pointcloud2-at-a-certain-range/) by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-27**:
If I understand you correctly, I would actually recommend to use the CropBox nodelet filter in `pcl_ros`. That does exactly what you're after if I'm not mistaken.

**Comment by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on 2018-04-27**:
Is that going to work with the ros pointcloud2 format. I have never worked with the native pcl. Any advise on the use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it to work with the following loop

```
for(;iter_xx != iter_xx.end(); ++iter_xx, ++iter_yy)
    {
        point_dist = hypot(*iter_xx, *iter_yy);
        if (point_dist <= cut_off_dist)
        {
            memcpy (&pointcloud_out.data[counter2 * pointcloud_out.point_step + pointcloud_out.fields[0].offset],
                    &pointcloud_in->data[counter1 * pointcloud_in->point_step + pointcloud_in->fields[0].offset], sizeof (float));
            memcpy (&pointcloud_out.data[counter2 * pointcloud_out.point_step + pointcloud_out.fields[1].offset],
                    &pointcloud_in->data[counter1 * pointcloud_in->point_step + pointcloud_in->fields[1].offset], sizeof (float));
            memcpy (&pointcloud_out.data[counter2 * pointcloud_out.point_step + pointcloud_out.fields[2].offset],
                    &pointcloud_in->data[counter1 * pointcloud_in->point_step + pointcloud_in->fields[2].offset], sizeof (float));
            counter2++;
        }
        counter1++;
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) with karma: 38 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-04-27**:
Glad you've got this working. I was going to comment that this will be a very computationally expensive processes especially for large point clouds. Have you considered filtering either the farthest 20% of the depth range, or a threshold based on standard deviation? They could be much faster.

**Comment by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on 2018-04-27**:
It works so far, but of course its not a cheap calculation. I dont have any depth information. Which standard deviation do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

pcl_ros cropbox filter launched standalone, filtering everything behind the scanner and beyond 20 meters in front of it which ignores the request for a dynamic limit in the question but good enough for many other uses:

```xml
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pc2_cropbox"
    args="standalone pcl/CropBox"
    output="screen">
  <remap from="~input" to="/cloud" />
  <rosparam>
    min_x: 0.0
    max_x: 20.0
    min_y: -100.0
    max_y: 100.0
    min_z: -100.0
    max_z: 100.0
  </rosparam>
</node>
```